# Handlebars empty script in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have a simple Handlebars template script as follows

```
<div id="divId"></div>

<script id="tmpl-test" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each objects}}  
        <li> {{test}} </li> 
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

I have javascript like

```
var data=[{"test":"test"}];
var source = $("#tmpl-test").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$("#divId").prepend(template({ objects: data }));
```

But the page is not rendering. I tried Chromes inspect element. It is showing empty script.

```
<script id="tmpl-test" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

</script>
```

Why it is happening ? How I can solve this ?

Comment: It's above the script tag, I didn't added here

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nhuq29u9/), apparently not the whole picture is shown.